# How to play sound with Qt

Tags: qt, audio

How can I play sound with Qt? I tried this:

```
QSound::play("sounds/croack.wav");
```

QSound doesn't work on my ubuntu (seems that it requires NAS, although after I installed it it still doesn't work). Is there a simple one line Qt-only solution or do I need to throw in SDL or something else?

Comment: I tried QSound on Ubuntu, Windows and Mac and they all worked just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I have some progress, I can play ogg files but not wav (dunno why).

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <phonon/phonon>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app( argc, argv );
    app.setApplicationName("bla");
    Phonon::MediaObject *mediaObject = Phonon::createPlayer(Phonon::NoCategory, Phonon::MediaSource("sounds/4.wav"));
    mediaObject->play();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Compiled with ``` g++ ``pkg-config QtGui phonon --cflags --libs`` ```.

Comment: I really appreciate having such a minimal example, it's what finally let me get it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

You can use QMediaPlayer for both files format .mp3 and .wav

```
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer>

QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/path"));
player->setVolume(50);
player->play();
```

Comment: But make sure a platform codec is installed for MP3.

Comment: You must ensure that in the ".pro" file is included multimedia:

QT += multimedia

Answer (score 5):

Try with phonon. It's far more powerful than QSound. Here's a minimal example to play a video file. If you omit the VideoWidget, it should just play audio.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QUrl>

#include <phonon/audiooutput.h>
#include <phonon/mediaobject.h>
#include <phonon/mediasource.h>
#include <phonon/videowidget.h>

using namespace Phonon;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    QApplication app( argc, argv );
    app.setApplicationName( QLatin1String("testphonon") );
    const QUrl url = QUrl( QLatin1String("file:///somepath/somefile") );
    MediaSource src( url );
    MediaObject obj;
    obj.setCurrentSource( src );
    VideoWidget video;
    video.show();
    AudioOutput audio( VideoCategory );
    Phonon::createPath( &obj, &video );
    Phonon::createPath( &obj, &audio );
    obj.play();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I tried, but this does not work on my ubuntu, no sound is played.

Comment: @Helltone: Phonon is just a wrapper around native backends like gstreamer. If phonon doesn't work, it's either a problem with that backend (if one format works but another not it usually is), or with phonon not configured correctly. Check if some gstreamer-using video player has the same problems.

Comment: Is phonon standard? Which headers should I include?

Comment: @Helltone: What do you mean by standard? It's the API Qt provides for multimedia. My includes for the above example are <phonon/audiooutput.h>, <phonon/mediaobject.h>, <phonon/mediasource.h>, <phonon/videowidget.h>

Comment: This only work on Linux, some cross-platform Qt solution?

Comment: @Petr: These days I'd use qtmultimedia (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-index.html) for that.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options:

- QSound (which is broken beyond repair - don't use it)
- Phonon (will do what you want, but I found it to be "too much", especially when you just want to play a few notification sounds)
- Other libraries like SDL.

Comment: can u provide an example of just playing a sound?

Answer (score 4):

In QT5, Phonon has been removed from the official build. QSound works for the most part, but note that QSound does not support playing wave files with all sample rates( as I discovered the hard way). [QT5 QSound does not play all wave files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165608/qt5-qsound-does-not-play-all-wave-files).

If you use QSound, you can just play a wave like you did; but make sure you are playing a file from a disk; not a QT resource. Since the resources are not supported yet. You can copy a wave file from a resource to a harddrive on the fly and then play it; which is what I am doing in my application.

Answer (score 2):

I got that trouble too, i've solved it installing this package

```
qtmultimedia5-dev
```

and including in the ".pro" file

```
QT += multimedia
```