# how to play a wav file in qt

Tags: qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to play sound with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473608/how-to-play-sound-with-qt)

can anyone tell me how to play a .wav file in qt

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with qsound (it didn't work on my machine) so I needed to switch to Phonon. It's easy to use:

```
Phonon::MediaObject* _music;
_music = Phonon::createPlayer(Phonon::MusicCategory, Phonon::MediaSource(filename));
_music->play();
```

or better have a look into [the doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/phonon-mediaobject.html)

Comment: Please note that Phonon only works for **Windows *32 bits***.

Answer (score 0):

use QSound class to play a wave file. If you need to play more formats take a look at phonon