# Play notification (frequency x) sound in Qt - easiest way?

Tags: c++, audio, qt5.1

Qt 5.1 or later:

I need to play a notification sound of frequency x for n milliseconds. It'd also be nice if I could combine tones like this: 1000Hz for 2 secs, then 3000Hz for 1 sec, ..

The easiest way is to use files (WAV, MP3, ..), e.g. as described here: [How to play sound with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473608/how-to-play-sound-with-qt) But then I have to generate such files for each of my scenarios.

[Qt's audio output example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/examples/multimedia/audiooutput/audiooutput.cpp?h=5.14) generates such tones in memory ( `Generator::generateData(const QAudioFormat &format, qint64 durationUs, int sampleRate)` ). I could write such a generator for my purpose. But do I have to?

So what is the easiest way to just play frequency x for n milliseconds?

Comment: Have you figured out how to do that ultimately? I can't get into those tutorials, including the link provided by Jordan in the answer.

Comment: I have created a class for this in Qt and it works. However, this was a bit of a hack and also the class is incorporated in a project using some other classes which are not really relevant for the sound part. I can send the C++ class to you, but you have to figure it out on your own then. If, let me know how you want to get it. I will not paste it here as it does not comply with the SO rules and only cause downvotes.

Comment: It would be very kind of you to show your approach by pasting it on pastebin.com. I couldn't have figured how to create this class at all and I have found no clear turorials, so I'm stuck.

Comment: Have pasted the code "as is" here: https://pastebin.com/LW6zhafm Follow `CSoundGenerator::playSelcal` to get to the generating code

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To generate a tone in Qt, we can pass our own QBuffer to the QAudioOutput to be played.

Take a look at the [first example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html#details) on the QAudioOutput page.

What I did was create my waveform in a QByteArray.
Remember that `sin(2 * pi * frequency * i / sample_rate)` will give you a sin tone of the desired frequency:

```
#define FREQ_CONST ((2.0 * M_PI) / SAMPLE_RATE)

QByteArray* bytebuf = new QByteArray();
buf->resize(seconds * SAMPLE_RATE);

for (int i=0; i<(seconds * SAMPLE_RATE); i++) {
    qreal t = (qreal)(freq * i);
    t = t * FREQ_CONST;
    t = qSin(t);
    // now we normalize t
    t *= TG_MAX_VAL;
    (*bytebuf)[i] = (quint8)t;
}
```

Then we can take that buffer and do something like this to play it:

```
// Make a QBuffer from our QByteArray
QBuffer* input = new QBuffer(bytebuf);
input->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

// Create an output with our premade QAudioFormat (See example in QAudioOutput)
QAudioOutput* audio = new QAudioOutput(format, this);
audio->start(input);
```

If you need more example code, you can see how I did it in a little project I just started [here](https://github.com/jordan9001/SpectrumDraw).

Comment: I think you meant bytebuf instead of buf

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "window.h" package (not a QT one).
Then you just use the Beep(frequency, miliseconds).
For your example it should be Beep(1000,2000) and Beep(3000,1000) respectively.

Comment: Good and valid hint, but I need to run the app on different OSs.