# Beep tones with different frequency

Tags: qt

How to generate audible tones in `Qt` with different frequency.
For ex, in the following code, I use the same frequency `beep` in the three conditions.

But, I need three different sounds to indicate three conditions

```
   if(a_vertical> LevelOne )
    {  
        QApplication::beep(); 
    }
 else if(a_vertical> LevelTwo )
    {  
        QApplication::beep();
    }
 else
    {  
        QApplication::beep();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it directly in Qt. If you are on **Windows**, you can use **window.h** package to do that `Beep(frequency, milliseconds)`

However, in Qt, there are several other ways in which you can manipulate the sound. [Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310324/play-notification-frequency-x-sound-in-qt-easiest-way?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

```
#define FREQ_CONST ((2.0 * M_PI) / SAMPLE_RATE)

QByteArray* bytebuf = new QByteArray();
buf->resize(seconds * SAMPLE_RATE);

for (int i=0; i<(seconds * SAMPLE_RATE); i++) {
    qreal t = (qreal)(freq * i);
    t = t * FREQ_CONST;
    t = qSin(t);
    // now we normalize t
    t *= TG_MAX_VAL;
    (*bytebuf)[i] = (quint8)t;
}
```

Then we can take that buffer and do something like this to play it:

```
// Make a QBuffer from our QByteArray
QBuffer* input = new QBuffer(bytebuf);
input->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

// Create an output with our premade QAudioFormat (See example in QAudioOutput)
QAudioOutput* audio = new QAudioOutput(format, this);
audio->start(input);
```